# How to merge object properties inside an object belonging to a Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to implement a reducer with a 'comments' object which holds arrays of comments indexed by some ID. I want to merge and not replace the properties inside the 'comments' object.

Right now I have this:

```
commentsReducer {
   comments: {}
   1: Array[9]
   2: Array[5]
   isFetchingComments: true
   lastUpdated: null
}
```

My Reducer function:

```
function commentsReducer(state = {
   isFetchingComments: false,
   lastUpdated: null,
   comments : {}
   },action){

  switch(action.type){      
    case RECEIVE_COMMENTS:
      var new_cm = {[action.pid]: action.comments};
      return Object.assign({}, state, new_cm); 

  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
commentsReducer {
   comments { 
      1: Array[9],
      2: Array[5]
   }
   isFetchingComments: true
   lastUpdated: null
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
var new_cm = {comments:{[action.pid]: action.comments}};
```

And it should do the trick

**Edit**

if you want to add more comments then

```
var new_cm = {comments: Object.assign({}, state.comments, {[action.pid]: action.comments})};
```

Comment: That way replaces the comments property.

Comment: I thought you wanted to replace the comments property with the new comments

Comment: second solution has some weird behavior. It changes properties outside comments. I think I'm just going to go with the first solution, although it replaces the property.

Comment: @JoãoLima Opps you're right, i forgot something, updated in the new edit - should work now.

Comment: Working as intended. Thank you so so much.

Answer (score 0):

try jQuery's function: 

     `$.extend();`

---

#### example:

```
var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var obj2 = {
   b:3,
   c:4
};
var obj3 = $.extend({},obj1,obj2);
console.info(obj3);
```

the result is :
{
 a:1,
 b:3,
 c:4
}

---

wish this will work for you ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
switch(action.type){      
  case RECEIVE_COMMENTS:
    var new_cm = Object.assign({}, state.comments, {[action.pid]: action.comments});
    return Object.assign({}, state, new_cm); 

}
```